# Why can't I sometimes switch weapons with Torbjörn?

Tags: overwatch

In almost every game, after placing the turret with Torbjörn I have problems switching to the hammer to upgrade it.

At first, I thought it was just my mouse wheel acting up, but even pressing 1 or 2 (keys for the different weapon slots) shows the same phenomenon: The gun gets lowered and raised again.

Is there a known problem with Torbjörns weapon switching?

When using i.e. Mercy, my mouse wheel seems to be a bit buggy as well, but the keys work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a known issue with [Torbjorn weapon switching,](https://www.google.com/search?q=torbjorn%20weapon%20switch&rlz=1C1MSNA_enUS672US672&oq=torbjo&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l3.1190j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) especially with Mercy's weapons as well.

Unfortunately there is no fix as of yet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen on the Xbox version